# Showing an image as url using jboss 7.1

Tags: linux, image, url, configuration, jboss

Friends I want to show an image like

```
http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8085/images/c4.jpg
```

But don't understand how to do it from my server cane any one helpme i am using **jboss-as-7.1.1.Final**  all the helps are available foe Jboss 6.
Actually my requirement is in server i want to keep a directory where all the image will be store and I can access any image will  **url** 
I am using Linux environment .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a images directory under `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/welcome-content`, as long as you haven't disabled that in your configuration. Your config file (e.g. `standalone.xml`) should have:

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
```

Alternatively you can deploy static content. See a example in http://java.dzone.com/articles/deploying-static-content-jboss

Comment: Can you tell me how to access an external directory form jboss I mean to say i have a directory like `/Home/Images` and i want to access some picture from there through URL .

Comment: @smn_onrocks If you are using linux you can try create a symbolic link to the `welcome-content`directory. Eg `ln -s /Home/Images images`